# Testing the Uniformly Most Powerful Test against the alternative

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Hi I am working on the following problem

A single observation $X$ is made from one of three densities listed below with parameter space $\Theta=\{0,1,2\}$.
\begin{align*}
x=0\hspace{0.4cm}x=1\hspace{.4cm}x=2\hspace{.4cm}x=3\hspace{.4cm}x=4\\
f(x|\theta=0)\,\,\,\,\,\, 0.05\hspace{0.9cm} 0.05\hspace{0.9cm} 0.40\hspace{0.9cm} 0.50\hspace{0.9cm}0.00\\
f(x|\theta=1)\,\,\,\,\,\, 0.30\hspace{0.9cm} 0.40\hspace{0.9cm} 0.05\hspace{0.9cm} 0.20\hspace{0.9cm}0.05\\
f(x|\theta=2)\,\,\,\,\,\, 0.40\hspace{0.9cm} 0.30\hspace{0.9cm} 0.10\hspace{0.9cm} 0.10\hspace{0.9cm}0.10
\end{align*}

a) Find the likelihood ratio test of size $\alpha=0.1$ for testing $H_0: \theta=0$ against $H_1: \theta=\{1,2\}$

b) Is the test in part a UMP against the alternative? Why or why not?

c) Determine whether there exists a UMP test of size $\alpha=0.05$ for testing $H_0: \theta=0$ against $H_1: \theta=\{1,2\}$.

I got the part (a) which is 
\begin{align*}
R=\{x\in\{0,1,4\}\}\\
\alpha=P_{\theta=0}(x\in\{0,1,4\})
\end{align*}

I am stuck with (b) and (c) any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you know what is UMP test? and how to check for that?

Comment: @Seyhmus Güngören Yes by using Neyman-Pearso Lemma or Karlin Rubin Theorem.

Comment: that sounds good. lets say we choose NP lemma, how should we apply it here to see if there is a UMP test? do you think that KRT can directly be applied here?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören What do you mean KRT?

Comment: What about Short for Karlin Rubin Theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Hints, in something approaching plain English. I hope you will learn something by expanding them carefully to give details and use formal
notation as in your text:

In (a) there is really only one LR test at level 10%, and you have
found it. Thus "uniformly" is easily satisfied in (b).

However in (c), there are two LR tests at level 5%, having
rejection regions $\{0,4\}$ and $\{1,4\}$. But respective
powers against $\theta = 1$ and $2$ are .35 and .45 for $\{0,4\},$
and .50 and .40 for $\{1,4\}$. So one rejection region is
better for $\theta = 1$ and the other is better for $\theta = 2,$
and that's not "uniformly" most powerful.